# How can I search multiple sites in a site collection (but not ALL of them)?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to display a list of posts in a Content By Search web part. I only want posts from sites within the site collection that were created with my custom web template. Is this possible? I was thinking that I could filter based on a custom property in the SPWeb, but everything I'm seeing seems to indicate I can only search based on the metadata of the posts themselves.

Answer (score 0):

With standard SP form I guess it's not possible. But you could build your own search form...

1. add a search results webpart.
2. edit webpart
3. click "Change query"
4. To get the search input from user choose "Value of a field on the page" as filter.
5. additionaly you can what ever filter you want here